# Cannot Set Higher Screen Resolution on Debian 10 w/ ThinkPad T420 and Samsung UE850 Monitor

Tags: debian, x11, cinnamon

I am trying to set a higher resolution on my Debian 10.3 system. I am using Cinnamon as my desktop environment. My machine is a Lenovo ThinkPad T420 type 4236 and I have an external Samsung UE850 monitor.

I used the following commands to try and set a higher resolution:
1. cvt 2560 1440 #gives me the modeline
2. xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
3. xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 "2560x1440_60.00"

I can then go to settings->display and see the new mode I added. When I select it and select "Apply" I get the following error:

"Could not set the configuration for CRTC 63"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would try the 5.4 kernel from backports.

Comment: I tried the 5.4 kernel from backports and that did not work.

Comment: Have you tried `xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 2560x1440_60.00` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this to work. It turns out that the video cable was the issue. I was using a DisplayPort-to-HDMI video cable and this was not allowing the higher video resolutions. I then replaced it with a standard DisplayPort cable (i.e. DisplayPort on both ends) and as soon as I did that the higher video resolutions were available and worked fine.